# angularjs routing template not working

Tags: angularjs

below code works fine in stackoverflow console, but not on my browser. 
BAsicall ngRoute not working for me.Appreciate your help. New to angularJS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<a href="#banana">Banana</a>
<a href="#tomato">Tomato</a>

<p>Click on the links to change the content.</p>

<p>The HTML shown in the ng-view directive are written in the template property of the $routeProvider.when method.</p>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        template : <h1>Main</h1><p>Click on the links to change this content</p>
    })
    .when("/banana", {
        template : <h1>Banana</h1><p>Bananas contain around 75% water.</p>
    })
    .when("/tomato", {
        template : <h1>Tomato</h1><p>Tomatoes contain around 95% water.</p>
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Two things that jump out at me: 1) you are missing the `https:` from your `angular-route.js` script reference and 2) the `template` values should be enclosed in quotes because they are strings in your sample code.

Comment: What isn't work, the routes or the anchors? You should be using ng-href

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the templates with quotes,

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        template :"<h1>Main</h1><p>Click on the links to change this content</p>"
    })
    .when("/banana", {
        template : "<h1>Banana</h1><p>Bananas contain around 75% water.</p>"
    })
    .when("/tomato", {
        template : "<h1>Tomato</h1><p>Tomatoes contain around 95% water.</p>"
    });
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/RfOy5ZrvteqrwSsmG614?p=preview)**

Comment: i did that. still not working. shows "/" template but not other 2 whec\n clicked.

Comment: @laput did you check the demo i added

Comment: yes i did. the same code works on stack overflow console. but not working on my browser. I am running apache webserver. So wondering it must be other than code.

Comment: check if the angular and angular route version are same